# when i click edit button nothing show in the edit form this the error

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting the following error:

> http://localhost/sites/admin_panel/student_center_system/controller/admin/editmaster.php?item_id=
> **Notice**: Undefined variable: row in **C:\xampp\htdocs\sites\admin_panel\student_center_system\controller\admin\viewitems.php** on line **49**

when i click edit button on viewitem.php nothing shows up in the form it is empty this viewitems.php The database connection is working perfect but the problem is the edit form .Ihave been stack  for two days with this problem about edit form not working.could someone help me please i will appreciate thank you.

[image]

```
   <?php 
        include "navigation.php";
        include "header.php";
        include "footer.php";
    ?> 
    <?php

        include("../dbConfig.php");

        $query = "SELECT item_id,item_name,description,item_category,pic FROM lost_items_table";
        $returnD = mysql_query($query);
        $returnD1 = mysql_query($query);
        $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($returnD);

    ?>

                <!-- Page Content -->
            <div id="page-wrapper">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <h1 class="page-header">View Items</h1>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                                        <div class="panel-heading">View Items</div>
                                        <table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Item Id</th>
                                                <th>Item Name</th>
                                                <th>Description</th>
                                                <th>Item category</th>
                                                <th>Picture</th>
                                                <th>Edit</th>
                                                <th>Delete</th>
                                            </tr>
                                            <?php
                                                while($result1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($returnD1)){
                                                ?>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <a href="adminPage.php?activity=itemdetails&item_name=<?php echo $result1['item_name']; ?>"> <?php echo $result1['item_id']; ?> </a>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td><?php echo ucfirst($result1['item_name']); ?></td>
                                                    <td><?php echo ucfirst($result1['description']); ?></td>
                                                    <td><?php echo ucfirst($result1['item_category']); ?></td>
                                                    <td><?php echo ucfirst($result1['pic']); ?></td>
                                                    <td>    
                                                        <a href="editmaster.php?item_id=<?php echo $row["item_id"]; ?>">Edit</a>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <a href="adminPage.php?activity=deleteitem&item_name=<?php echo $result1['item_name']; ?>">Delete</a>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <?php
                                                }
                                            ?>

                                        </table>
                                        <!-- /.table-responsive -->
                                       </div>
                                    </div>
                                        <!-- /.panel -->
                                </div>
                                    <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.row -->
                </div>
            </div>
```

this is editmaster.php file.this is the form for editing data and nothing is showing up in the form its empty.what could be wrong with my code .

```
     <?php session_start();
            include("../dbConfig.php");
            include "navigation.php";
            include "header.php";
            include "footer.php";

        {

        } 
                        $item_id = '';
                        $item_name = '';
                        $description = '';
                        $item_category = '';
                        $pic = '';
                        if (isset($_POST['updateitem']))
                        {

                            if (is_numeric($_POST['item_id']))
                        {

                            $item_id = $_POST['item_id'];
                            $item_name = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['item_name']));
                            $description = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['description']));
                            $item_category = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['item_category']));
                            $pic = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['pic']));

                        if ($item_name == '' || $description == '' || $item_category == '' || $pic == '')
                        {

                        $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';

                        valid($item_id, $item_name, $description, $item_category, $pic, $error);
                        }
                        else
                        {

                        mysql_query("UPDATE lost_items_table SET item_name = '$item_name', description = '$description', item_category = '$item_category', pic = '$pic' WHERE item_id = '$item_id'")
                        or die(mysql_error());

                        header("Location: viewitems.php");
                        }
                        }
                        else
                        {

                        echo 'Error!';
                        }
                        }
                        else

                        {

                        if (isset($_GET['item_id']) && is_numeric($_GET['item_id']) && $_GET['item_id'] > 0)
                        {

                        $item_id = $_GET['item_id'];
                        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM lost_items_table WHERE item_id=$item_id")
                        or die(mysql_error());
                        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

                        if($row)
                        {

                        $item_name = $row['item_name'];
                        $description = $row['description'];
                        $item_category = $row['item_category'];
                        $pic = $row['pic'];

                        valid($item_id, $item_name, $description, $item_category, $pic,'');
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        echo "No results!";
                        }
                        }
                        else

                        {
                        echo 'Error!';
                        }
        }

        ?>



               <!-- Page Content -->
                <div id="page-wrapper">
                    <div class="container-fluid">               
                                        <!-- /.row -->
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <!--div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4"-->
                                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                                <div class="Register-panel panel panel-default">
                                                <!--div class="panel panel-default"-->
                                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                                        Edit Item
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                                        <div class="row">
                                                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                                                <div class="panel-body">
                                                                    <form role="form" action="adminPage.php">
                                                                                <input type="text" name="item_id" value=<?php echo $item_id; ?> readonly><br>
                                                                                <input type="text" name="item_name" required autofocus placeholder="Item-Name" value=<?php echo $item_name; ?>><br>
                                                                                <input type="text" name="description" required autofocus placeholder="Description" value=<?php echo $description; ?>><br>
                                                                                <input type="text" name="item_category" required autofocus placeholder="Item_category" valu
e=<?php echo $item_category; ?>><br>
                                                                                <input type="text" name="pic" required autofocus placeholder="pic" value=<?php echo $pic; ?>><br>

                                                                                <input type="submit" name="updateitemBtn" value="Update">
                                                                    </form>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: `mysql_query` Ouch. `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, you should switch to `mysqli` or PDO.

Comment: You don't POST your form but try to access `$_POST['updateitem']`. Also, there isn't even an input named `updateitem`.

Comment: This line: <a href="editmaster.php?item_id=<?php echo $row["item_id"]; ?>">Edit</a>   Do you mean  $result1["item_id"] ??? I didn't see you declaring $row

Comment: in viewitems.php i have used $result1 and in the editmaster.php i have used $row